# How to programatically add and rename tabs in tabstrip of a vba user form?

Tags: vba

I've been trying to write a program which will add a new tab on in tabstrip of vba. I need to do this in run-time. I have an "add tab" button to add it. And at the same time it will rename the tab as a series e.g. "Add Tab">> "Nozzle 2", "Add Tab">> "Nozzle 3" and so one. Any help? Following is the code I tried but it is showing type mismatch error, why?- I don't understand. I tried with similar code for multipage and it worked. But why isn't it working for Tabstrip??

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim newPage As Tabs
Dim PagesCnt As Long

With Me.TabStrip1
   PagesCnt = .Count
   Set newPage = .Tabs.Add("Nozzle" & (PagesCnt + 1), "Nozzle " & (PagesCnt + 1), PagesCnt)
   UserForm1.TabStrip1.Value = PagesCnt
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tabs` is a *collection* of tabs, so you can't set it as a single tab

the proper *type* for a *tab* control is `MSForms.Tab`

```
    Dim newPage As MSForms.Tab
```

but you don't need it altogether:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim PagesCnt As Long

    With Me.TabStrip1
       PagesCnt = .Count
       .Tabs.Add "Nozzle" & (PagesCnt + 1), "Nozzle " & (PagesCnt + 1), PagesCnt
       .Value = PagesCnt
    End With    
End Sub
```

and you can get rid of `PagesCnt` variable, too:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Me.TabStrip1
      .Tabs.Add "Nozzle" & (.Count + 1), "Nozzle " & (.Count + 1), .Count
       .Value = .Count - 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It just works great! Thanks a lot, @DisplayName. But can you please explain why didn't it work with my code? Difference seems insignificant.

Comment: Ok, I get it. "Tabs is a collection of tabs, so you can't set it as a single tab" Isn't it the reason?

Comment: You are welcome. You may then consider marking the answer as accepted. Thank you. As for the explanation I gave it in the very first lines of my answer.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. And as you asked, I marked it accepted... my mistake. I should have done it first time. Thank you again. Cheers!

Comment: One more thing (I am wondering, should I ask it in comment or ask a new question?). Now I want to perform some task using the value I put in a textbox of tabs. Each tab will receive different values in a number of textboxes, store/save them and use them on button click. In my code if I change value of one tab it changes values of previous tabs also which is not expected. Solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: You’d better make a new post with your code attempts at solving the new issue

Comment: Hi, can you please answer my question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772938/how-to-get-values-from-controls-on-tabstrip-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

The example below uses the `Style` property to specify the appearance of the tabs in `MultiPage` and `TabStrip`. This example also demonstrates using a `Label`. The user chooses a style by selecting an `OptionButton`.

More information at [**the source**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/outlook-vba/articles/how-to-set-the-style-of-tabs-for-a-multipage-and-a-tabstrip-control).

> ```
> Sub OptionButton1_Click()
>     Set MultiPage1 = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("P.2") _
>           .Controls("MultiPage1")
>     Set TabStrip1 = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("P.2") _
>           .Controls("TabStrip1")
>     MultiPage1.Style = 0 '0=fmTabStyleTabs
>     TabStrip1.Style = 0 '0=fmTabStyleTabs
> End Sub
>
> Sub OptionButton2_Click()
>     'Note that the page borders are invisible
>     Set MultiPage1 = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("P.2") _
>           .Controls("MultiPage1")
>     Set TabStrip1 = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("P.2")_
>           .Controls("TabStrip1")
>     MultiPage1.Style = 1 '1=fmTabStyleButtons
>     TabStrip1.Style = 1 '1=fmTabStyleButtons
> End Sub
>
> Sub OptionButton3_Click()
>     'Note that the page borders are invisible and
>     'the page body begins where the tabs normally appear.
>     Set MultiPage1 = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("P.2")_
>          .Controls("MultiPage1")
>     Set TabStrip1 = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("P.2")_
>          .Controls("TabStrip1")
>     MultiPage1.Style = 2 '2=fmTabStyleNone
>     TabStrip1.Style = 2 '2=fmTabStyleNone
> End Sub
>
> Sub Item_Open()
>     Set Label1 = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("P.2")_
>          .Controls("Label1")
>     Set OptionButton1 = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("P.2")_
>          .Controls("OptionButton1")
>     Set OptionButton2 = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("P.2")_
>          .Controls("OptionButton2")
>     Set OptionButton3 = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("P.2")_
>          .Controls("OptionButton3")
>     Set MultiPage1 = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("P.2")_
>          .Controls("MultiPage1")
>     Set TabStrip1 = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("P.2")_
>          .Controls("TabStrip1")
>
>     Label1.Caption = "Page/Tab Style"
>     OptionButton1.Caption = "Tabs"
>     OptionButton1.Value = True
>     MultiPage1.Style = 0 '0=fmTabStyleTabs
>     TabStrip1.Style = 0 '0=fmTabStyleTabs
>
>     OptionButton2.Caption = "Buttons"
>     OptionButton3.Caption = "No Tabs or Buttons"
> End Sub
> ```
>
> <sup>[(Source)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/outlook-vba/articles/how-to-set-the-style-of-tabs-for-a-multipage-and-a-tabstrip-control)</sup>

Comment: I went to the source. But this was not what I wanted to do. My question isn't about formatting but adding & changing caption of tabs.

Comment: Hey, you reported in my other question that this question and that one are duplicate of one another. You are wrong. These two are completely different questions. The thing is you didn't understand my first question and answered wrong neither you did understand my second question. Reporting a question without full understanding isn't polite. It looks like some kind of revenge attitude of why I didn't endorse your answer here.