# How to get values from controls on tabstrip in VBA?

Tags: vba

In different tabs of a tabstrip I have input values which are different in each tab. I need to write a code which takes all these values and do some work like sums up the values of each tab on button click.

Can anyone help me do this? In my code when I input value at a textbox of one tab it also changes the value of all other tabs and hence cannot receive different values of each tab. Any idea, please?

[image: Please click here to check what I am trying to do and what suppressing me to do this]

Comment: If the controls on all the tabs are changing at once, either there is only one control that isn't on a tab (it's on top of the tabstrip control) or else maybe you have them all named the same.  Find out by deleting one.  You should be able to refer to a control on a tab from the userform code something like `me.TabStrip1.Tabs(0).Controlnamehere`.  (untested).  There are a number of tutorials about working with tabs (although not very many, since they're kind of a big pain for little benefit.) Also see [ask] and [mcve] for some tips.

Comment: I know how to "refer to a control on a tab from the userform code" when the controls are put individually at each tab and in that case tab numbers are per-defined in user form. But my tabstrip has only one tab initially which increases on button click and one textbox put on first tab which is also replicated at each new tab. How can I refer to this new control (e.g. textbox) when it is in the new tab?

Comment: You might want to look into using a mulipage instead of a tab strip....

Comment: @Mistella Multipage is good for different controls but my controls are same with different values which is why tabstrip is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Multipages vs Tabstrips**

---

A multipage is an object with "pages". Each page can hold it's own collection of controls which can then be referenced either directly or through the containing page object.

A tab strip is an object with "tabs". Unlike a "page" object, a tab does not have it's own controls. Instead, there are **only** the original controls, visible for all "tabs".

*Programmatic differences*

Since a multipage has a different set of controls for each page, there is very little housekeeping required. The selection of a page affects which controls are visible, and the controls automatically retain values assigned to them (as expected).

For a tabstrip, since there is only the **initial** set of controls, there is a lot of housekeeping required in the code. The selection of a tabstrip does not have any automatic effect on the values in the controls. Instead the controls act as *would* be expected if they were not in the tab strip at all.

---

**Tabstrip Solution**

---

Set up a variable (array, collection, dictionary) that can be used to hold the various values of the controls. Then, in the `TabStrip_Change()` event, store the previous value, and reset the control for the new tab (or fill in the value the new tab last held).

I recommend adding a userform level variable `Dim old_tab as Long` which you can set to the current page at the end of the `TabStrip_Change()` event. (This is useful for retrieving previously filled values for the correct tab).

For my sample code, I will be using an array. However, since arrays are not very flexible with changing lengths, you can also look into using either a dictionary or collection, if desired.

For the userform pictured below, the following code causes the single textbox to act as though there is a different textbox per tab. It also saves the values whenever the tabstrip changes. (Note: if you then use the saved values for the calculation, remember to update the value for the current tabstrip first.)

```
Option Explicit
Dim old_tab As Long
Dim textValues As Variant

Private Sub TabStrip1_Change()
    textValues(old_tab) = TextBox1.Value 'Saves the old value
    TextBox1.Text = textValues(TabStrip1.Value) 'Updates value to reflect tab change
    old_tab = TabStrip1.Value 'updates tab # variable
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ReDim textValues(0 To TabStrip1.Tabs.Count - 1) 'tabs are zero-based, so count is always one more than the maximum tab value
    old_tab = TabStrip1.Value 'Ensures that the first value will be saved to correct location at the tab change
End Sub
```

[image: Sample Userform with tabstrip with two tabs and one textbox]

Comment: Finally, someone realized the real problem and I got the perfect solution.

Comment: Can you please help me on one more thing?- How can I call a saved value for further calculation? For example, I want to add textbox values from different tabstrips. I've been trying array but still couldn't find a way. Don't mind for my silly question. I am a bit new with VBA.

Comment: I'm not sure from your brief description what the issue is, plus this seems like an issue where it would be nice to see your attempted code with an example/explanation of what you want vs what the code is actually doing. I think it would be better for you to ask a new question about it. If you post a link to it in a comment here, I'll check it out.