# Copy TextBox in UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

So, this is a problem... I have an UserForm with several TextBoxes in one Page. Inside a loop, I need to copy all those TextBoxes, create new Page, paste TextBoxes and fill them with new data. My problem is how to enter values into those pasted TextBoxes?

```
        Do While wkbSource.Sheets("WorkingSheet").Cells(lin1, rng.Column) <> ""

        currCell = wkbSource.Sheets("WorkingSheet").Cells(lin1, rng.Column)           
        currDlUarfcn = wkbSource.Sheets("WorkingSheet").Cells(lin1, rng.Column + 3)
        currPsc = wkbSource.Sheets("WorkingSheet").Cells(lin1, rng.Column + 4)
        currRootSeqIdx = wkbSource.Sheets("WorkingSheet").Cells(lin1, rng.Column + 5)
        currZone = wkbSource.Sheets("WorkingSheet").Cells(lin1, rng.Column + 6)
        currCellId = Right(currCell, 1)

        'Enter data in first Page
        Site.txtLteCellName = currCell
        Site.txtLteCellId = txtLteBtsId
        Site.txtLteUarfcnDl = currDlUarfcn
        Site.txtLteAzimuth = currAzimuth
        Site.txtLtePsc = currPsc
        Site.txtLteTac = currTac
        Site.txtLteRsi = currRootSeqIdx
        Site.txtLteLoCellId = currLoCellId
        Site.txtLteSector = currSector
        Site.txtLteSectorEq = currEquipmentId
        Site.txtLtePower = "40W"
        Site.txtLteCabinet = currCabinet
        Site.txtLteSubrack = currSubrack
        Site.txtLteSlot = currSlot

        'Create new page, copy and paste textBoxes
        Dim l As Double, r As Double
        Dim ctl As Control

        MultiPage4.Pages.Add

        MultiPage4.Pages(0).Controls.Copy
        MultiPage4.Pages(1).Paste

         For Each ctl In MultiPage4.Pages(0).Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.Frame Then
                l = ctl.Left
                r = ctl.Top
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        For Each ctl In MultiPage4.Pages(1).Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.Frame Then
                ctl.Left = l
                ctl.Top = r
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        lin1 = lin1 + 1

    Loop
```

[UserForm image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xroLq.jpg)

Comment: Well, if you believe you're up to handling the coding for the required housekeeping for a tabstrip, you might want to consider using it instead of a multipage. Here's a link to a comparison I gave between the two. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52239345/9259306

Answer (score 0):

For experimental purpose i use the below reference:

UserForm:frmTest
TextBox:txtTest

Try:

```
    With frmTest '<= Refer to the userform with it s name
        .txtTest.Value = "Finished" '<= Refer to text box with it s name & assign value
    End With
```